# .tex Notes for Overview with Inline Comments for Non-LaTeX Users?

Tags: collaboration

**Problem**: WYSIWYG documents used by majority of my colleagues; I know I have better content in my notes but I cannot share/present it time-efficiently for them, without confusing them with excessive inline comments. They are just my notes so I do not want to work them for publication quality. Inline comments (`%...`) are necessary in the output.

**Goal**. Prioritise textual content from inline comments (`%...`) where different subenvironments (`%%...` for start of one content; `%$...` possible better sign for typical inline comments).

- I need to collaborate with non-LaTeX users. I am thinking how I can well print .pdf from my notes for the overview.
- I need the comments too because they essential for the understanding.
- I do not want to use any non-full LaTeX package for changing my way of writing notes. I love the full semantics, but my colleagues can get confused especially about inline comments.
- Comments. I keep in Comments Sources, some Source codes and explanation.  They are necessary because I have there many times hyperlinks which extend/visualise the case much further.

Ways for Visualisation in parsing full-LaTeX Semantics to them

- Colorise/italize/makeSmaller inline comments (`%...`).
- Separate double comment environment (`%%...`)
- New environment in inline comments etc (`%$...`)
- I think Tikz can be the tool here.

Example with dummy content

```
\section{1.1.2016 Bowel obstruction. Classification. DX. Diff DX}

%% Sources
% http://apps.who.int/iris/bitstream/10665/75146/1/9789241548441_eng.pdf#page=35
% dia.pdf#page=534
% liver 3.pdf

% Localisation of hernias
Bowel obstruction. 

Small bowel obstruction (SBO).
\begin{enumerate}

\item DX 

    Examination.
    Percussion. % liver border, has to do 
    Auscultation. 
    % 
    Prognosis of patient: % recommendations 

    % Serious. 
    % Cholecystitis with % fistula to skin. 
    % Cholecystectomy convential; bleeding postoperative (hematoma in abdominal cavity), ...

    %% Hypertension 
    % Level  Systolic Diastolic  
    % normal <120     <80 
    % pre    120-139  80-89 
    % I      140-159  90-99
    % II     >160    >=100

\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}

\item Lorem

    Physics: 
    Diffusion, ultrafiltration, convection. 

\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}

\item Procedure

     Lorem

\end{enumerate}

\section{19.5.2016}
% Lorem

\section{20.5.2016}
% Lorem

\section{23.5.2016}
% Lorem

\section{24.5.2016}
% Lorem

% Indications.
Treatment  
\begin{itemize}

    \item Definition. 

\end{itemize}


\section{25.5.2016}
% Masi

%% 26.5.-3.6. from 11-14
\section{26.5.2016}
% Masi

\section{27.5.2016}
```

### Separate environments

- `verbatim`. Too raw without prioritising content from inline comments.
- `minted`. I think it cannot work well for the whole document.
- `listings`. It is designed for source code, not for text and comments. So I think not the right tool here.

### 1. Shorten long links in inline comments

Etc input http://apps.who.int/iris/bitstream/10665/75146/1/9789241548441_eng.pdf#page=35. 
It would be nice to have output like `who...eng.pdf#page=35` which the hyperlink on it. 
I think this is not possible to do without extra semantics.

I think this can be also be solved by making comments small and with smaller linespace.

### 2. Tables in inline comments starting as double comment mark (`%%`)

See the example for the input. 
I think Windows help-file (*.h*) way making a new document about tables with a link to the source coudl work here very well.

### Review of UlrikeFischer's answer

I think if-else structure by design can have difficulties to work well. 
A systematic approach can work better: functions to bring specific characteristics. TODO functions.

1. Test 1. 
   Matching `%%` should not match `%.*%`. 
   Data `%\include{8.9.2015.tex} % Masi`. Other test data `% About 75\% efficiency of transplants work.` This test data passed by 2nd edit of Ulrike.

Application of dual comment coloring (`%.*%`) overflows many semantics commands (`\section`, ...) if `%%` just before them.

```
\section{25.5.2016}
% Masi

%% 26.5.-3.6. from 11-14
\section{26.5.2016}
% Masi

\section{27.5.2016}
```

Expected output: *26.5.-3.6. from 11-14* in green, section *26.5.2016* in black*, and *Masi* in red. Output: all in green after `%%`

[image]

Incomplete evidence because the example above does not show it. TODO

2. Insertion of pagebreaks causes complications. 
   I think it may be related to tabs `\t` which is before the word *Diffusion*. Test data 2

   ```
   \begin{enumerate}

   \item Lorem

       Physics: 
       Diffusion, ultrafiltration, convection. 

   \end{enumerate}
   ```

Expected output is one liner: *Physics: Diffusion, ultrafiltration, convection*. Output

[image]

3. Test data 3

   ```
   \begin{enumerate}

   \item Procedure

        Lorem

   \end{enumerate}
   ```

Expected output: word *Procedure* in black. Test passed after Ulrike's 3rd input.

4. Test data 5

   ```
   \section{19.5.2016}
   % Lorem

   \section{20.5.2016}
   % Lorem

   \section{23.5.2016}
   % Lorem

   \section{24.5.2016}
   % Lorem
   ```

Expected output: 24.5.2016's comments are in red. 
Passed after Ulrike's 3rd input.

5. Test case 6

   ```
   % Indications.
   Treatment  
   \begin{itemize}

       \item Definition. 

   \end{itemize}
   ```

Expected output: *Indications* in red, *Treatment* in black, and the dot of *Definition* in black. 
Output: *Treatment* in black, and the dot of *Definition* in red

[image]

6. Test case 7: How to handle underscores/hashtags in inline comments?

Input

```
% http://apps.who.int/iris/bitstream/10665/75146/1/9789241548441_eng.pdf#page=35
```

Expected output: link in red without formatting. 
Solution

```
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/309617/13173
\catcode`\_=12 % disable function of underscores 
\catcode`\#=12 % disable function of hashtags
```

7. Test case 8: have URLs which have percentage signs

Input

```
% http://apps.who.int/%%%iris/bitstream/10665/75146/1/9789241548441_eng.pdf#page=35
```

Output `http://apps.who.int/iris/bitstream/10665/75146/1/9789241548441_eng.pdf#page=35`.
Expected output `...%%%iris...`. 
**Solution**: expand links before having them in inline comments. 
I think this feature is not critical.

8. Test case 9: Prioritise more early inline comments in the same line

Input

```
% masi is lorem ipsun % this is less important but % even more less important`
```

Current output: `masi is lorem ipsun this is less important but even more less important` where is no prioritizing.

9. Test case 10: include .tex files in the main document

Code

```
\include{8.9.2015} % this is a comment
```

Expected output: like text in the main document. Output: many errors. Something internal in `\include` probably causing it.

---

How Can you Print .pdf from .tex Notes with Visualised Inline Comments for Overview for non-LaTeX Users?

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to achieve. `todonotes` package? If the comments are essential for understanding, why are they comments?

Comment: But you're asking how to make a PDF that includes the comments ... Or do you just want the source, verbatim?

Comment: Masi, you manage to surprise me again and again with questions that make me think: *What the heck is he trying to do?* If i understand the question (would be the first time) this is a complete mixup betweeen Input/Output vs. You/collegues. This is like four corners of a square and i have no idea which edge shall communicate with which edge.

Comment: So you want the source verbatim? Only highlighted with different colours, sort of like the snippet of code above? Then look at `minted` or `listings`. There are probably a few thousand questions on the site describing them, so search a bit and/or look at the manuals. If that is not what you want, you really need to explain better what "better than verbatim" means.

Comment: So, you want to share a pdf file that contains the tex code as you wrote it but makes comments (starting with `%`) a bit smaller and colored?

Comment: Well then, see what @Torbjørn wrote almost half an hour ago.

Comment: What you are asking for is not possible. In order to share useful information with your mates, you need to prepare a good version for them to read. If i make notes during a presentation and want to share the information, i cannot simply ask a program to automatically recognise the little hangman i drew and to remove it. I need to work on my notes before giving them away.

Comment: Different approach: Describe the to a friend, or a rubber duck or a pencil. Once you can describe the problem with real sentences, improve the question. Still, i think i don't understand it.

Comment: @Johannes_B Improved again. I think a solution here can only be a package which is designed for text and comments. Not for source code and its comments.

Comment: As a TeX neophyte (or worse) ... the issue here (it seems to me) is that `%...` comments are being used as "inline notes". They aren't really "comments" in the typical "coding" sense -- which are intended to REMOVE that material from text flow. Here, the "comments" *add* information *necessary* to the text flow. Solution: don't use TeX `%...` comments, but some other form of appropriate markup which retains that material in the text flow. No?

Comment: @David Do you have any recommendations about how "comments" can be reached? I would not like to include my inline comments in the text flow; they are just for my colleagues so I think they should be preceded by `%...` but probably sign like `%$` could help here; not sure how well it can work in practice because no current separation between such comments `%$` and comments `%` in the editor colorisation. Probably, auto-folding for `%...` comments somehow but not for `%$`.

Comment: Would you mind improving the question in bigger parts. Every few seconds the *an edit has been made* thing plops on. And since this all happens within 5 minute blocks, i cannot track the changes.

Comment: Another thing, do you realise that your text is the source code of your document?

Comment: Two more edits while writing a comment, outta here.

Comment: @Johannes_B Yes, done now. I will do it so next time. See the body.

Answer (score 5):

Well tikz is certainly not the tool. But you can naturally change the meaning of e.g. %. The problem is that it is not easy to confine the change "until the end of the current line". The best is imho to read the file line by line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\newif\ifdoublecomment
\newif\ifincomment
\newcommand\commentstyle{\ifdoublecomment\color{green}\bfseries\else\color{red}\footnotesize\fi}

\begingroup
\catcode`\%=13
\def%{\@ifnextchar%{\doublecommenttrue\commentstyle\incommenttrue}{\commentstyle\incommenttrue}}

\newread\myread
\openin\myread=testinput.tex
\@whilesw\unless\ifeof\myread\fi{
\read\myread to \dataline
\dataline
\ifincomment\par\fi\color{black}\normalsize\normalfont\incommentfalse\doublecommentfalse}
\closein\myread

\endgroup
\end{document}
```

### Testinput.tex:

```
Small bowel obstruction (SBO).
\begin{enumerate}

\item DX

    Examination.
    Percussion. % liver border, has to do
    Auscultation.
    %
    Prognosis of patient: % recommendations

    % Serious.
    % Cholecystitis with %fistula to skin.
    % Cholecystectomy convential; bleeding postoperative (hematoma in abdominal cavity), ...

    %% Hypertension
    % Level  Systolic Diastolic
    % normal <120     <80
    % pre    120-139  80-89
    % I      140-159  90-99
    % II     >160    >=100

\item blblbl
      blblblb
      bllblb
\end{enumerate}
```

### Output

[image]

It is imho possible to make the links active (and shorter) with the help of e.g. xstring -- you only need to check if the line contains a http but you should be aware that while it is easy to setup such a simple case and to devise solutions for all your wishes the fine tuning and the actual implementation can be very time consuming.

Comment: I edited the definition to avoid that %.*% matches. If you use \include  in the comments this naturally will now be executed, give a pagebreak  *and will not be read line by line*, so the coloring will not work. As I wrote: fine tuning this sort of things can be very time consuming.

Comment: Test cases 2, 3 and 5 are not passed. I think the insertion of pagebreak causes some complications, see test case 2. I think bug in test case 2 is caused by reading tabs `\t` as pagebreak.

Comment: I inserted another conditional to avoid the \par if the previous line wasn't a comment. But I really don't want to spent the next week to adapt the code to your test files. So this was the last change I made ...

Answer (score 0):

Not enough reputation here to comment, but I wanted to say that you can probably use something like Markdown or Pandoc.

If that's not enough, you can use a templating engine to set up everything in LaTeX, and write your notes in YAML or something. I used Jinja2 with Python to automatically generate my resumes. (https://github.com/masasin/resume)

Comment: No, thank you for these proposals! I have done many attempts on them, and Ulrike's answer is much much better at the moment than those two tools can ever provide.