# How to Disable Function of Underscores?

Tags: catcodes

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
http://apps.who.int/iris/bitstream/10665/75146/1/9789241548441_eng.pdf#page=35
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Wanted output: no special effect of underscores.

---

How can you disable the current function of underscores?

Comment: Although there's a way to do it, it's not recommended. Can't you just load the `url` package, and wrap URLs in `\url{...}`?  That will work.

Comment: @AlanMunn I suspect this is connected to [.tex Notes for Overview with Inline Comments for Non-LaTeX Users?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/309541)

Comment: @AlanMunn I really would like to disable it. I cannot use it `\url{...}`  in all environments. So I really need it. Tor's pointed out thread is one example where I will have problems with `% http://...`.

Comment: Load the `underscore` package then.  That should probably do the trick. You need to make sure you're using a font encoding (minimally T1 if using pdflatex) that supports the _ character. But you'll also have to escape things like `#` too.

Comment: @Masi Ever heard of `\urldef` from the package `url`? It can be used in all environments. Problem solved. Simply do what you're supposed to do and do not re-invent America.

Comment: @yo' Yes, but I cannot understand its benefit here http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/url/url.pdf By it, I think you cannot have inline comments as `% http://...`.

Comment: You can have any comments anywhere except _inside_ verb-like contexts. But why in the world would you put a comment there?!

Comment: @yo' Can you propose a better approach? I use a lot of comments in inline comments.

Comment: @Masi Well, your example does not show any comment. Sorry, but no issue, no answer. Honestly, you're more cryptic than Cleopatra.

Comment: @yo' Of course, not here because it is not related. You can assume it youself `% This is a very useful comment, http://...`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 \catcode`\_=12
```

will make `_` a normal punctuation character.

You will need

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

as OT1 encoded fonts don't  have a `_` in the ASCII slot.

Comment: How can you disable hastag (`#`)? I tried unsuccessfully `\catcode \`#_=11`. How did you know which number you can use for the mapping?

Comment: @Masi you don't want a `_` in the `#` version:-) just replace `_` by `#` in the above any tex tutorial will tell you the catcodes 11 is letter 12 is punctuation 13 is active

Comment: @Masi 12, presumably, like `_`

Comment: @Masi you did something wrong then

Comment: @Masi it works as described. You  must have made an error somewhere

Comment: @Masi because I used the code I described and you have an obvious typo with the setting for `#` having a spurious `_` presumably a cut and paste error.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I can do this with `url`'s `\urldef`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{url}

\urldef \myCuteLittleURL \url|http://whatever/under_score#hash%percent|

\begin{document}

Here I use the URL and have a comment at the very same place:
\myCuteLittleURL % http://whatever/under_score#hash%percent


\end{document}
```

[image]

---

I'm lost with your point about comments, so I included a comment.

Comment: Yes, one option. I will see how the changed catcodes will behave. If they fail, then I think this is a very good option.

Comment: They of course fail badly, once you have `%`s in your urls.

Comment: How can you solve the problem with comment signs inside urls?

Comment: @Masi As you see, I solved it. My url contains a `%`. Now I'm off, good night.

Comment: I think it is not necessary to have percentage signs in links because you can always expand them before having them in your document. I however created a test case about this problem (test case 8 here http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/309541/13173) for the future work.